# Why does invoking a function with a pointer to one member variable inhibit optimization of other member variable?

Tags: c++, optimization, language-lawyer

Consider the following program:

```
struct X {
    bool b;
    int y;
};

void f(int*);

bool test(X x) {
    if (!x.b) {
        return false;
    }
    f(&x.y);
    return x.b;
}
```

It seems that the statement

```
    return x.b;
```

does not get optimized to `return true;`
So my conclusion is, that the compiler must assume that `f(int*)` could modify `x.b` by doing this:

```
void f(int* p) {
    bool* q = reinterpret_cast<bool*>(p - 1);
    *q = false;
}
```

Is this implementation of `f` actually valid C++? Or differently phrased, must the compiler always assume that the entire object may change when a pointer to a member is passed to an opaque function?

Compiler output with clang-x86 trunk (-O1) is this:

```
test(X):                              # @test(X)
        push    rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rdi
        test    dil, dil
        je      .LBB0_1
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 4]
        call    f(int*)@PLT
        cmp     byte ptr [rsp], 0
        setne   al
        pop     rcx
        ret
.LBB0_1:
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

[See live demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/a66EKE5xE)

One interpretation I can come up with, is that the given definition of `f` is valid C++ if I only ever call it like in the example above and so the compiler must assume that possibility.

Comment: No, such implementation of `f` is straight up UB. Now whether `return true;` is faster than `return x.b;` might be up to debate...

Comment: @Yksisarvinen So what you are saying is, that a conforming compiler could assume that the call `f(&x.y)` (whatever the definition of `f`) cannot change `x.b`? (Considering that `x` is not aliased since it's a local variable)

Comment: Conforming compiler should assume that aliasing any object field leads to aliasing of the entire object. And it is actually a relatively common practice, for example it is used in boost and in php.  `X * p_object{reinterpret_cast<X *>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(p) - offsetof(X, y))}; ...`

Comment: @user7860670 Thank you, that's what I wanted to know. Could you perhaps point me to the relevant section in the standard?

Comment: btw. the impl of f - really is UB. subtracting an int pointer to get the bool field...
This usually works because of 3 padding bytes, but...
It would not work if the platform says the alignment requirement for int is 1 - than you would access data before the struct.

Comment: @Bernd Yes, I guess I should at least be using the `offsetof` macro, see 
user7860670's comment for reference

Comment: I'm almost a bit surprised (disappointed?) that the compiler didn't optimise to `if(x.b) { f(&x.y); } return x.b;`, which is what I'd have written right in the first place anyway...

Comment: @Aconcagua I guess if `x.b` is very unlikely, then this would be a pessimization because the memory would be read twice.

Comment: @chrysante Well... looks as if GCC [does so](https://godbolt.org/z/xdPTxK1En) with -O3 ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the shown implementation of `f` leads to undefined behavior, it can be implemented in correct manner:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

void f(int* p)
{
   static_assert(::std::is_standard_layout_v<X>);
   X * p_object{reinterpret_cast<X *>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(p) - offsetof(X, y))}; 
   p_object->b = false;
}
```

So compiler may assume that aliasing any field of object of standard layout type leads to aliasing of entire object.

Comment: I assume this question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385020/can-code-that-will-never-be-executed-invoke-undefined-behavior
Behaviour is well defined as long as `p` always points to an `X::y` member when `f` is invoked.

Comment: Also in practice any real-life compiler should probably assume that aliasing any field of object even of non-standard layout type leads to aliasing of entire object. For example boost heavily relies on stuff such as [parent_from_member](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/boost/intrusive/detail/parent_from_member.hpp). I think that uncontrolled aliasing is actually one of the major limiting factor of the performance of C++ programs (compared to Fortran for example, where, as far as i know, compiler is free to assume no aliasing).

Answer (score 8):

The shown implementation of `f` is certainly undefined behavior. However, the compiler not only owes conformity to the C++ language, but also to platform specific behaviors that do permit that `x.b` is changed.

The compiler does not see how `f` is implemented. What if it was written in assembly? Such an implementation certainly may do what it wants, including changing `x.b` without violating any specifications and standards. Hence, it must assume the worst and re-read `x.b`.

Answer (score 4):

You rely on padding in your implementation so that is definitely UB.

I believe the following implementation is not undefined behaviour if called with `f(&x.y)`.

```
void f(int* ptr){
    X* x = reinterpret_cast<X*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr)-offsetof(struct X,y));
    x->b=true;
}
```

Anyway, Linux kernel itself heavily relies on the struct being reachable from a pointer to its member via [`container_of`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832301/understanding-container-of-macro-in-the-linux-kernel) macro so regardless what behaviour is defined or not, mainstream compilers do assume reachability and will not optimize this case.